# Elasticsearch - number of users online

Tags: time, elasticsearch

I have a data about my users that represents when each user has logged in and logged out.

I want to query the sum of users in a specific interval (minute, hour, ...) using ElasticSearch. Does anyone know how to get this kind of query?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be to store a document representing the stay of each user - timestamps for login and logout times, and a value (in milliesconds for example) representing the duration of stay. It then becomes super easy to query.

Personally I would probably just output this info to logs and use logstash to shovel it into Elasticsearch

See a discussion about both here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/logging-elasticsearch-events-with-logstash-and-elasticsearch/